# Sharing folder between Obj-C project and Swift 4 project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Basically, I have 2 projects running, one is in obj-c and another is in Swift 4 and I want them to access their directory folder in order to exchange their resources in the run-time. Right now my approach is accessing document directory of Swift 4 project via:

`FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`

so it will generate the path like:

> /Users/public1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/22D423BD-C28D-45B7-A976-D9FB02409988/data/Containers/Data/Application/3B15E00A-910B-420E-8047-99F2E6E5013D/Documents

And if I want get the same Documents directory of obj-c project, I will use above path, delete 2 last components path:

> /Users/public1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/22D423BD-C28D-45B7-A976-D9FB02409988/data/Containers/Data/Application

then using `enumerator.nextObject()` to find the flag of obj-c project. It works perfectly fine in simulator but in the device, those code counters a problem is that when running on a device, those folders won't be on the macOS folders but in device folders, so the URLs executes by above code is something like:

> /var/mobile/Containers

and I neither can find nor access to that folder so that my enumerator won't work. So is there a way to accessing that folder (using code) or some mechanism to get 2 project folder shared with each other?

=========================================================

EDIT: for using [AppGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) I added those code in my Obj-C project:

```
NSUserDefaults *pathShared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] nitWithSuiteName:@"com.example.myDomain"];

[pathShared setObject:directoryPath forKey:@"path"];
```

and in Swift 4 code:

```
let userDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.example.myDomain");

let path = userDefault?.object(forKey: "path");
```

but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Your English sentences are almost incompresensible because you keep writing without using the period.

Comment: Sorry because English is not my primary language, I editted and added an example of using FileManager for my appoarch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language that you are using to implement application is not a reason. It is just a different applications with different [sandboxes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). In iOS one application can't get access to files from a sandbox of other application. You can share data between applications by using same [AppGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) for the applications, after that you can use shared [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init) and write and read files from a shared [directory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati?language=objc):

```
<...>
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: @"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];
[mySharedDefaults setObject:theAccountName forKey:@"lastAccountName"];
<...>

NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManger];
NSURL* url = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:[self appContainerName];
<...>
```

Comment: I tried your appoarch but some how it didn't seem to work, my answer editted above!

Comment: Also you should execute this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, the sandbox will prevent your app from accessing any other app's data, even if you developed the other app yourself, too. However, you can set up an App Group and entitle both of your apps to access it, and that will allow you to share what you want. The *Sharing Data with Your Containing App* heading on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) has a good overview on how to do that